# How to check if input is equal to preset value in C programming?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm writing a program where you allow someone to login. but i can't make it print successfully login when the id and password i input is equal to the preset value.

```
int main()
{
 int id,pass,idC=0,passC=0,i,myid,mypass,tries=1;
 myid = 10082612;
 password = 123456;

 printf("**LOG IN**\n\n");
 printf("ID: ");
 scanf("%d", &id);
 printf("Password: ");
 scanf("%d", &pass);

 while(id != 0){
    id /= 10;
    idC++;
 }

 while(pass!= 0){
    pass /= 10;
    passC++;
 }

 if(idC==8 && passC ==6 || idC==7 && passC==6){
    if(id==myid && pass==mypass){
        printf("Successfully Login");
    }
    else{
        printf("Unknown ID");
    }
 }
 else if(idC!=8 && passC==6 || idC!=7 && passC==6){
    printf("The Student ID should be in 7 or 8 digits, please try again");
 }
 else if(idC==8 && passC!=6 || idC==7 && passC!=6){
    printf("Please enter a 6-digit pin");
 }


}
```

This is what I've wrote.

Comment: Just use `if(id==myid && pass==mypass)` and it all

Comment: What is `password`? The code you posted here doesn't compile.

Comment: In code you are changing `id` and `pass` entered by user (`id /= 10;` and `pass /= 10;`). Their value will always be zero when while loop breaks, so thats why your `if(id==myid && pass==mypass)` condition is failing. To correct it, store it in different variable and proceed.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - Evidently, password is:   `password = 123456;`

Comment: after your double loop `pass` and `id` will be 0

Comment: @ryyker possibly, yes still, the code doesn't compile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because you're losing the original values of `id` and `pass` due to:

```
while(id != 0){
    id /= 10; //THIS PART
    idC++;
 }

 while(pass!= 0){
    pass /= 10; // AND THIS PART
    passC++;
 }
```

To avoid this, you can :

```
int idCopy = id;
int passCopy = pass;
 //and then do

 while(idCopy != 0){
    idCopy /= 10;
    idC++;
 }

 while(passCopy!= 0){
    passCopy /= 10;
    passC++;
 }

//and use the original values of id and pass like in your code .
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your idC  and passC to 1 because for a 8 digit number the loop is only true 7 times and so on.

```
int idC = 1,passC = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

check the below code. in your code you are updating id and pass values. That's why you can't successfully login

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int id,pass,idC=0,passC=0,i,myid,mypass,tries=1;
 myid = 12345678;
 int password = 123456;

 printf("**LOG IN**\n\n");
 printf("ID: ");
 scanf("%d", &id);
 printf("Password: ");
 scanf("%d", &pass);
 int temp=id;
 while(temp != 0){
    temp /= 10;
    idC++;
 }
temp=pass;
 while(temp!= 0){
    temp /= 10;
    passC++;
 }

 if(idC==8 && passC ==6 || idC==7 && passC==6){
    if(id==myid && pass==password){
        printf("Successfully Login");
    }
    else{
        printf("Unknown ID");
    }
 }
 else if(idC!=8 && passC==6 || idC!=7 && passC==6){
    printf("The Student ID should be in 7 or 8 digits, please try again");
 }
 else if(idC==8 && passC!=6 || idC==7 && passC!=6){
    printf("Please enter a 6-digit pin");
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the value of id and pass change after the while. Thanks for the help. Here is the solve one. Again thanks!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 int id,pass,idC=0,passC=0,i,myid,mypass,tries=1,idCopy,passCopy;
 myid = 1234567;
 mypass = 123456;

 printf("**LOG IN**\n\n");
 printf("ID: ");
 scanf("%d", &id);
 printf("Password: ");
 scanf("%d", &pass);

 idCopy = id;
 passCopy = pass;
 while(idCopy != 0){
    idCopy /= 10;
    idC++;
 }

 while(passCopy!= 0){
    passCopy /= 10;
    passC++;
 }

 if(idC==8 && passC ==6 || idC==7 && passC==6){
    if(id==myid && pass==mypass){
        printf("Successfully Login");
    }
    else{
        printf("Unknown ID");
    }
 }
 else if(idC!=8 && passC==6 || idC!=7 && passC==6){
    printf("The Student ID should be in 7 or 8 digits, please try again");
 }
 else if(idC==8 && passC!=6 || idC==7 && passC!=6){
    printf("Please enter a 6-digit pin");
 }


 }
```

Comment: FYI, it is rarely necessary, after having identified another answer as _Accepted_, that you also add your own answer unless it clearly adds something of lasting relevance to the discussion.  In this case I am not sure it does.  But since the answered question did not fully address your issue, and the poster of that answer put the onus on you to fix it, ( _No problem, you can make an edit..._ )  mark your own answer as _accepted_.

Comment: I meant to add an edit in your question itself, I'm sorry if I was vague. And instead of anonymously getting down voted, I can take down my answer if it did not point out the mistake.

Comment: With `while(idCopy != 0){
    idCopy /= 10;
    idC++;
 }` and `id == 0`, this results in `idC == 0`.  I'd expect 1.  Consider `do {... } while(idCopy != 0)`

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj did I down voted you? If i did I'm sorry, I did not mean to, I don't really know how to use this website. Can I undo it? Sorry.

Comment: @ryyker Im sorry, I'm quite new to the website, and don't really know how the answers and voting works. Sorry. I think I even mistakenly down voted someone who actually helped me.